# Laravel 5.6 token to access all routes including login and register routes

Tags: php, laravel, rest, token

I am creating a new rest API using Laravel 5.6. For API authorization, I have implemented Passport and it is working fine.

However, I want a system where anyone who wants to access any route of my API including register and login that requires token.

I am thinking in this way but not so sure how I can implement in Laravel.

- I will issue one static token and will store into database.
- I will encrypt that token and will provide to the client in my case
  mobile app.
- Mobile side the token I will store into shared preference so no one
  will have direct access.
- When mobile send a request to access any route of API, it has to pass the token in the header with the custom key
- API will decrypt the token and match with the database one.
- If it matches that will allow accessing the API.

Then later I may use the Passport token to add additional layer or security.

> **My question is,**
>
> How to implement this system in Laravel so I don't have to write code
>   for every request and all request pass through this validation?

Comment: issue a token at the start (this will be a session token). use a single client token and put scope => *  (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#issuing-access-tokens) | on /oauth/token send username:username
password:pass
grant_type:password
client_id:1 (or whatever comes first. it's in the passport tables somewhere)
client_secret:your_client_secret_used_for_all_clients
scope:*  on every request: Headers Bearer {token} where token is the token you generated for that session. I hope I understood what you meant. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Indra thanks for your reply. As I said, I have already implemented Passport and set the `grant_type` to `password`. This is not exactly what I am looking for as it is allowing to access @register and @login routes without requiring any token. What I want is any client who wants to access any route even `@register` or `@login` or `@index` or any other they must have to verify token. I don't know if Passport provides such feature and I may overlook or didn't understand that.

Comment: you don't need to go to login or register after that. You can skip that using a middleware  and putting all the api routes in this : Route::group(
        ['middleware' => ['auth:api',

Comment: in class VerifyCsrfToken add  protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ]; and hopfully you prefixed all your api routes with api/

Comment: You can create one authenticate function on controller, where you need to validate the header token. Call this authenticate function into your constructor. when you hit any route belong to this controller it will first hit authentication function.  Let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: @Jyotimishra I think this will be a good starting point to test. Just one question. Is there anyway so I don't even have to add a method to the constructor? I mean some other way like middleware etc?

Comment: Yes, you can also create one middleware , where you need to check header token and validate this. I have not implemented this yet but i think this is also possible.

Comment: @CodeLover use the middleware like i wrote. I already did that for 3 applications and it never fails. Also don't forget about VerifyCsrfToken. I can write you a tutorial, but it will take at least a day until I have time and idk if you can wait

Comment: @Indra I appreciate your help. I am confused with `CsrfToken`. I am looking for the solution on `API` routes, not the `WEB` routes.

Comment: It's for the api routes. i wrote above in class VerifyCsrfToken add protected $except = [ 'api/*' ];